# Beginner input validation issue

Tags: python

Write a program that prompts the user to input a sequence of words. The program then displays a list of unique words (words that only occurred once, i.e. no repeated).

I've tried getting rid of the input validation, but then if the user inputs any value. The program breaks.

```py
list5 = []
game_over = False

while game_over is False:
    user_input = input("Please enter a word: ")
    list5.append(user_input)
    keep_it_going = input("Would you like to enter more words? (Y / N): ")
    while len(keep_it_going) != 1 and keep_it_going.lower() != "y" or "n":
        print("You entered an invalid value, please try again!")
        keep_it_going = input("Would you like to enter more words? (Y / N): ")
    if keep_it_going.lower() == "y":
        continue
    elif keep_it_going == "n":
        game_over = True
```

I expect the program to run as I don't see any logic lapses, however once I enter a value of "Y" for "Would you like to enter more words? (Y/N): ", the program tells me I've entered an invalid value.

Comment: Change `xxx != "y" or "n"` to `xxx not in ("y", "n")`.  The former groups as `(xxx != "y") or "n"` which of course is always true.

Comment: You also have an `and` which should be `or`.  But the entire length test is redundant, just get rid of it.

Comment: Since this is probably not obvious for a beginner: in python, an empty string (`""`) evaluates to false, non-empty strings (e.g. `"n"`) evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

```
while len(keep_it_going) != 1 and keep_it_going.lower() != "y" or "n":
```

is your problem. It should be neither "y" nor "n" to be a false input so you need to change it to the following:

```
while len(keep_it_going) != 1 or keep_it_going.lower() != "y" and keep_it_going.lower() != "n":
```

Comment: This is still a bad answer.  Look at my comments on the original post.  Your test is 3 times longer than it needs to be.